# shinylive does not read data from external sources

Tags: r, shiny, r-shinylive

I have been trying to read .csv file from my computer or online sources to incorporate in shinylive, but the dashboard does not show anything at all.

````
---
title: "Wine Data Analysis"
format:
  html:
    grid:
      body-width: 1400px
filters:
  - shinylive
---

```{r, results='hide', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
#| context: setup
data <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv")
```

```{shinylive-r}
#| standalone: true
#| viewerHeight: 600
library(shiny)

#Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$table <- renderTable({data[1:10,]})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````

Result:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at your `data`? When I load it, I have 1599 rows and 1 column, the first row being `"7.4;0.7;0;1.9;0.076;11;34;0.9978;3.51;0.56;9.4;5"`. Use `read.csv2` (since it uses `sep=";"`) and you'll get 12 columns. That might have nothing to do with why shiny-live isn't doing what you expect, but at least you'll have meaningful data when it does.